# Best Practice for promise based actions

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am creating an app using reactjs and mobx. The app calls an external api using promise. As soon as the promise returns i would like to redirect to another page. I would like to know how it should be done, right now I intend to redirect from the store as soon as the promise returns, but i don't know if this is the best way to go. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: just do the redirect in the callback from the request. you dont need to put that logic in the store. let the store worry about getting data and storing it.

Comment: I guess i am viewing this from an MVC point of view. Because i am calling the stores method from a component that represents my view. So i am wondering if its right to change route from that view.